# BtvStack.exe error - utils.dll missing

Tags: windows-8.1

I bought a new WIndows 8.1 notebook from Lenovo (S210 touch) and after starting it I received the error `BtvStack.exe error - utils.dll missing`

How to fix the error?

Full error dialog:

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a bluetooth driver issue. Re install [bluetooth driver](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/ideapad-s-series-netbooks/ideapad-s210-notebook/?tabName=Downloads) from [Lenovo](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products?tabName=Downloads) website

Comment: Thanks but I get a 404 for my device: Lenovo S210 Touch - Are there safe alternatives to download the driver

Comment: You tried this link http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/ideapad-s-series-netbooks/ideapad-s210-touch-notebook?TabName=Downloads

Answer (score 1):

#### I get a 404 for my device: Lenovo S210 Touch

> Are there safe alternatives to download the driver?

Bluetooth drivers for Windows 8.1 can be found on the Lenovo website.

1. Go to [S210 Touch Laptop (IdeaPad)](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/ideapad-s-series-netbooks/ideapad-s210-touch-notebook?c=1)
2. Select the "Downloads" tab
3. Click [Bluetooth Driver (Intel, CyberTan, Liteon) for Windows 8.1 (32-bit, 64-bit) – IdeaPad S210,S210 Touch](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/ideapad-s-series-netbooks/ideapad-s210-notebook/downloads/DS037632)

The download location is http://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles/bt135w81.exe